# Meteor Large Scale App - unclosed <body>

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on a large scale enterprise app in Meteor. The problem I've run into is that once my html pages get over 900+ lines long I begin to sporadically (more often with more lines of code) get the following error:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: unclosed <body> - line 7, file /var/www/www.######.com/#######.html
<body>
    at new html_scanner.scan.parseError (/usr/lib/meteor/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:23:14)
    at Object.html_scanner.scan (/usr/lib/meteor/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:92:15)
    at /usr/lib/meteor/packages/templating/package.js:46:32
    at _.extend.add_file (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:195:5)
    at self.api.add_files (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:96:16)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:79:11)
    at self.api.add_files (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:95:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:79:11)
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

If I refresh my page several times, it will eventually work and I know there is no unclosed  tag. I'v run the html through several html lint programs with no errors. My code is proprietary, so I can't post it, but was wondering anyone else has run into this issues?

I'm wondering if there is an issue with the html_scanner but don't have the time to debug the templating package. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reduce your situation to a reproducible test case that you can post in a gist? Eg. a basic 900+ line HTML file that causes the same problem you're describing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have tested a html file with 3134 lines in a Meteor 1.0.3.1 project and everything went smoothly. No error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to come up with a 900+ line sample to replicate the issue but couldn't do it with the basic html I was coming up with. I did come up with a solution that will hopefully help someone else. Instead of having one large html and since templating is already built in, I created a separate html for each 'view' in template tags:

```
<template name="testView">(content)</template>
```

And then injected each view back into the html main page using:

```
{{> testView }}
```

It seems to have solved the issue above, my main html page is down to 300 lines and each view is in its own html file.

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to be complaining about an unclosed  tag. I would check your HTML and make sure you closed all your tags properly.

Unrelated to your specific problem, but I ran into a similar error when wrapping my template in  tags.